# Calculating Jaccard distance between every element of 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, data-science

I want to calculate the Jaccard Distance between 2 dataframes. Specifically, I want to compute the pairwise Jaccard distances between all the Google entities (34000 rows, 7 cols) and all the Amazon entities(34000 rows, 7 cols) separately using CountVectorizer model. I created a countVectorizer for each dataframe as follows:

```
cv = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,1), stop_words='english', binary=True)
cvGoogle = cv.fit_transform(goog_s)
cvAmazon = cv.fit_transform(amaz_s)
```

After creating a CountVectorizer, I need to create a data structure where I compare each of the entities of the two vectors using `Jaccard Distance` and store it in a dataframe where each row corresponds to an entity from the Google dataset and each column corresponds to an entity from the Amazon dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to loop through the cols with using either [sklearn Jaccard distance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html) or [scipy Jaccard dissimilarity](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard.html).

*If you want to compare two matching entities, then*

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import jaccard

my_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Assuming goog_s & amaz_s to be pd.DataFrame objects
for g_col, a_col in zip(goog_s.columns, amaz_s.columns): 
    my_df.loc[:, '_'.join([g_col, a_col])] = jaccard(goog_s[g_col].tolist(),
        amaz_s[a_col].tolist())
```